# how to connect two database servers, namely one local and one more live servers in CodeIgniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

how to connect two database servers, namely one local and one more live servers in CodeIgniter ?
1 local server 
and 1 more server live

how to connect two database servers, namely one local and one more live servers in CodeIgniter ?
1 local server 
and 1 more server live

```js
$active_group = 'default';
$query_builder = TRUE;

$db['default'] = array(
 'dsn' => '',
 'hostname' => 'localhost',
 //'username' => 'skyware',
 //'password' => 'skyware',
 'username' => 'root',
 'password' => '',
 //'database' => 'zadmin_kagum',
 'database' => 'zadmin_afung',
 'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
 'dbprefix' => '',
 'pconnect' => FALSE,
 'db_debug' => TRUE,
 'cache_on' => FALSE,
 'cachedir' => '',
 'char_set' => 'utf8',
 'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
 'swap_pre' => '',
 'encrypt' => FALSE,
 'compress' => FALSE,
 'stricton' => FALSE,
 'failover' => array(),
 'save_queries' => TRUE
);

$active_group = 'cloud';
$query_builder = TRUE;

$db['cloud'] = array(
 'dsn' => '',
 'hostname' => 'localhost',
 'username' => 'afungdbuser',
 'password' => 'IQGCnqsK9',
 'database' => 'zadmin_afungdb',
 'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
 'dbprefix' => '',
 'pconnect' => FALSE,
 'db_debug' => TRUE,
 'cache_on' => FALSE,
 'cachedir' => '',
 'char_set' => 'utf8',
 'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
 'swap_pre' => '',
 'encrypt' => FALSE,
 'compress' => FALSE,
 'stricton' => FALSE,
 'failover' => array(),
 'save_queries' => TRUE

);
```

db_cloud is server live , and default server local

Comment: This question is rather broad, it would help if you specify with some form of example of what you want to do. Do you simply want to have it switch between local / production depending on the environment?

Answer (score 0):

when you use the code in local keep `$active_group = 'default';` as it is. When you move code to live change `$active_group = 'cloud';`. Check it might help you.